# Editors with many widgets have horrible performance

Tags: themes, e4

*We switched to e4 target platform. One editor has became horrible slow with rendering (about 20 seconds to layout). When a modal dialog is opened from the editor-menu, the application flickers like having an epileptical fit.*

When we turn off css, by ...

```java
DefaultScope.INSTANCE.getNode("org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.renderers.swt")
    .put("themeEnabled", "false");
```

*in the plugin, the rendering is very fast (<10ms), like it used to be under the previous target platform.*

this is the control that i have embedded into the editor (for evaluation reasons):

```java
package xyz;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;

public class BigControl extends Composite {

    public BigControl(Composite parent, int style) {
        super(parent, style);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(23, false));
        for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
            for (int j=0; j<23; j++) {
                new Label(this, SWT.NONE).setText("|" +  Integer.toString(i) + " " + Integer.toString(j) + "|");;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*has anybody experience with that problem? Yes, we know that a table would be better for such amount of data, but refactoring that would cost too much at the moment.*

The second problem is, when we turn off the theme functionality, eclipse / swt brings up exceptions when switching perspectives, views and so on.

Comment: Seems to work quickly on macOS but that number of controls is a bad idea. You will be getting close to the limits on some platforms.

Comment: Thank you, as I told, we have no time to replace it by - let's say - a nattable. The control is very complex, so we can forget about it now.

Answer (score 1):

OK, we replaced the target platform by a newer one (2019-3). I was not aware about using an older platform.

**The flickering stopped**, it is still not fast (resizing the window takes about 2 seconds), but it is acceptable for the moment.

Thank you for your help,

Best, Martin

Answer (score 0):

... to make things clear, I created a brand new application by the eclipse wizard (... having a view).

I replaced the sample views code by that - **as I mentioned, when we turn off css/theming (see code above), everything is fine** - otherwise it doesn't stop to shake, it is even hard to get the mouse pointer back to eclipse to stop the app:

```
package xyz;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Label;
import org.eclipse.ui.part.ViewPart;

public class View extends ViewPart {
    public static final String ID = "xyz.view";

    public class BigControl extends Composite {

        public BigControl(Composite parent, int style) {
            super(parent, style);
            setLayout(new GridLayout(23, false));
            for (int i=0; i<100; i++) {
                for (int j=0; j<23; j++) {
                    new Label(this, SWT.NONE).setText("|" + Integer.toString(i) +     " " + Integer.toString(j) + "|");;
            }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void createPartControl(Composite parent) {
        new BigControl(parent, SWT.NONE);
    }


    @Override
    public void setFocus() {
    }
}
```